# How to track Excel selection complete action

Tags: excel

Is there a way to know Excel selection complete action?
I'm aware of the SheetSelectionChange, ExcelSheet.SelectionChange and ExcelSheet.Change events. But I want to know the Selection completion as i need to set focus back on my components in Excel.

Is there any event which serves the purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you use the [`Selection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa196885%28v=office.11%29.aspx) object ?

Please elaborate your question if it doesn't answer what you wanted.

Comment: I need to track the event when user stops selection of cells either by mouse or keyboard.

Comment: i can't see how you could know when the user has *finished* to make a selection (timeout, other action...). This is this last action you should track. Or else, the classical `SelectionChange` will fit your needs